# How to group pages by URL Parameter?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm attempting to analyze which regions of our homepage get the most attention. Backstory: I work for a local newspaper. The regions of our pages don't change, but the stories change every few minutes. Each story link contains a `ref` get parameter defining which region it was in.

What I'm looking for is a way to use a Google Analytics custom report to combine the links, but separate out the individual values of `?ref=[foo]`, which will let me know how much traffic each region of our homepage drives.

## Examples of sections

1.- OpinionBox:

http://example.com/2015/09/10/opinion/a-story-in-opinion/?ref=OpinionBox

2.- The PointBox
http://example.com/2015/09/10/the-point/a-story-in-the-point/?ref=The%20PointBox

3.- SportsBox
http://example.com/2015/09/10/sports/a-story-in-sports/?ref=SportsBox

4.- OutdoorsBox
http://example.com/2015/09/10/outdoors/a-story-in-outdoors/?ref=OutdoorsBox

5.- HomesteadBox
http://example.com/2015/09/10/homestead/a-story-in-homestead/?ref=HomesteadBox

6.- BusinessBox

http://example.com/2015/09/10/business/a-story-in-business/?ref=BusinessBox

7.- NextBox:

http://example.com/2015/09/10/next/a-story-in-next/?ref=NextBox

8.- FoodBox:

http://example.com/2015/09/10/food/a-story-in-food/?ref=FoodBox

9.- QuizzesBox:

http://example.com/2015/09/10/quizzes/a-story-in-quizzes/?ref=QuizzesBox

10.- EventsBox:

http://example.com/2015/09/10/events/a-story-in-events/?ref=EventsBox

As you can see, we have quite a few regions. I'm attempting to gather data about which regions drive the most traffic, so we can cut the number of regions we show on our homepage. Each region contains multiple links, each link for each region is appended with `?ref=[Region]Box` and I would like to combine each region into a single line in a custom report, so I can see how each region compares for page views.

Comment: May you post some examples of your urls... for example: www.newspaper.com/politics.... i'm interested in the "/politics" part.

Comment: @OmarGonzales I've added the examples you requested.

Comment: I see, I don't know if it's possible to make what you need with Custom Reports. I would recommend to export the data to a CSV (from the API), and the use regex (regular expressions) to group every section. I recommend that you use R or Python to extract the data.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is "Content Grouping". Please check the official help at:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2853423?hl=en

Answer (score -1):

If the `?ref=[foo]` is a parameter in the URL, you can make a segmentation in the report All Pages in Site Content from Behavior. 
To do this, you can create a new Segment and using a condition to list just the URL's that has "ref=".Another solution is a filter in the report that let just the URL's with "ref=". 
In either solutions, in the result, you can see which ref's had the most views.

Comment: What condition? Please provide examples.

Comment: The condition would be "ref=".The report, then, will show just pages that contains that part so, with the PageView metric, you can se which page has the most views

Answer (score -1):

If you need just quick result try to filter reports.

Behaviour - Site Content - All Pages

And fill your your ref parameter in filter box.

Like this: http://prntscr.com/8ud369

After filter apply you'll get filtered number of Pageviews.

Then repeat with all your ref params